# Can I run a Time Series Database (TSDB) over Apache Spark?

Tags: database, apache-spark, time-series, bigdata

I'm starting to learn about big data and [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/) and I have a doubt.

In the future I'll need to collect data from IoT and this data will come to me as [time series data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series). I was reading about Time Series Databases ([TSDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series_database)) and I have found some open-source options like Atlas, KairosDB, OpenTSDB, etc.

I actually need Apache Spark, so I want to know: can I use a Time Series Database over Apache Spark? Does it makes any sense? Please, remember that I'm very new to the concepts of big data, Apache Spark and all matters that I've talked in this question.

**If I can run TSDB over Spark, how can I achieve that?**

Comment: You should be able to, take a look at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.sources.package and an implementation such as https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/csv/CsvRelation.scala - I haven't found any OpenTSDB Java API, so you might need to go digging.

Comment: That's an interesting topic, but what do you mean by `TSDB over Spark`? Which part of the sensor data processing do you need to perform in the database and which part in Spark?

Comment: I need to store all time series in a good database and later I'll need Spark to use it's Machine Learning algorithms over this data.

Comment: @FernandoPaladini Should be no problem, can Spark act as a client, e.g. by executing REST queries or SQL queries via JDBC?

Comment: @SergeiRodionov I think the real problem that if you load data through REST API or SQL queries, it will be loaded at the driver process. Data will not be loaded distributively.

Answer (score 3):

I'm an OpenTSDB committer, I know this is an old question, but I wanted to answer. My suggestion would be to write your incoming data to OpenTSDB, assuming you just want to store the raw data and process it later. Then with Spark, execute OpenTSDB queries using the OpenTSDB classes.

You can write data with the classes also, I think you want to use the IncomingDataPoint construct, I actually don't have the details at hand at the moment. Feel free to contact me on the OpenTSDB mailing list for more questions.

You can see how OpenTSDB handles the incoming "put" request here, you should be able to do the same thing in your code for writes:

https://github.com/OpenTSDB/opentsdb/blob/master/src/tsd/PutDataPointRpc.java#L42

You can see the Splicer project submitting OpenTSDB queries here, a similar method could be used in your Spark project I think:

https://github.com/turn/splicer/blob/master/src/main/java/com/turn/splicer/tsdbutils/SplicerQueryRunner.java#L87